# Everything is missing!

Tags: unity, command-line, software-center

I've installed some not very good software. And now terminal is missing. Doing Ctrl + Alt + T does nothing. No left or top bar. There is nothing but the desktop. That's all. Software center is also missing so my ubuntu is ruined. Also I don't want to reinstall ubuntu then reinstall all my software.

Comment: your question information is misleading...!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this myself...

1. I right clicked on the desktop and created a new folder and called it whatever.
2. I opened it then I navigated to `/usr/share/applications/`
3. After that I opened this command line called `XTerm`.
4. I typed in `sudo apt-get install unity`
5. Then I typed in `sudo apt-get install software-center`

And everything was fixed.

Comment: The problem seems then not like *installing some bad software*, but *not uninstalling good software*.